# CSS transform, push/pull surrounding elements

Tags: css, transform

I'n using `translateY()` to pull an element up to overlap an element above it.

```
.element {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

It leaves space to the bottom. Is there any way to pull up any elements below it?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBYRMe

In the example you can see it overlaps the element on top which is what I want but leaves space on the bottom. I am trying to achieve this without modifying other elements (e.g. use transform on elements on the bottom as well)

Note: using margin -50% does not work because it doesn't bring up the element 50% relative to the element's height. Only transform calculates the height to my knowledge.

Comment: `transform` does **not** affect layout as it's purely visual - Negative margin is really the only method - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative big value in `margin-bottom` to pull the other elements:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.test, .element {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.element {
  width: 30%;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-bottom:-100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="element">:-)</div>
<div class="test"></div>
<br><br>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply transform on elements on bottom using the following css.I hope this is what you are looking for

```css
.element ~ div {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: element after that mean???.Here the transform is applied for all the div present below the class element.@DomenikReitzner

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-top: -50%;` instead. Happy coding

Comment: Margin top won't center the element vertical because it calculates relative to the width not the height when positioning -50%

Comment: Then the only solution would be to wrap everything that has to move up into a container, but if you have that behavior multiple times it will get very tedious. The problem you are facing, is if you look into the dev tools, that your element still sits in the same spot.

Comment: And if may point out: you do have an offset with `translateY` in Chrome of 8px to the bottom. You are not totally centered to start with 

Comment: The offset is caused by the element because I used inline-block in my example. Otherwise it is perfectly centered with translate.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the box-shadow properties to solve the your problem otherwise you can use the flex-box or position etc. anyway I gave solution but I'm not sure you want this things or not:)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.test, .element {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 60px 0;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.element {
  width: 30%;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow:0px 100px yellow; 
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="element">:-)</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.. and the codepen is just an example. It's not the actual code I'm working with.